# How to do an anti sway bar for a car in Unity 5?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, car

I have researched some examples of anti roll bars for Unity but they are all for unity 4 and bellow so they do not work in unity 5. Can someone please assist me in making an anti roll bar script in C# for Unity 5?

Here is the best example I could find (I don't know how to convert it for unity 5):

```
using System.Collections;

public class AntiRollBar : MonoBehaviour {

  var WheelL : WheelCollider;
  var WheelR : WheelCollider;
  var AntiRoll = 5000.0;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {

  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void fixedUpdate () {

    var hit : WheelHit;
    var travelL = 1.0;
    var travelR = 1.0;

    var groundedL = WheelL.GetGroundHit(hit);
    if (groundedL)
      travelL = (-WheelL.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).y - WheelL.radius) / WheelL.suspensionDistance;

    var groundedR = WheelR.GetGroundHit(hit);
    if (groundedR)
      travelR = (-WheelR.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).y - WheelR.radius) / WheelR.suspensionDistance;

    var antiRollForce = (travelL - travelR) * AntiRoll;

    if (groundedL)
      rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(WheelL.transform.up * -antiRollForce,
                                   WheelL.transform.position); 
    if (groundedR)
      rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(WheelR.transform.up * antiRollForce,
                                   WheelR.transform.position); 
  }
}
```

Comment: what errors are you getting ?

Comment: @UriPopov If possible please review my new code to check if it is valid because i have no way of knowing

Comment: For one, you seem to be trying to use the `FixedUpdate()`, but you call `fixedUpdate()`, instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You found your example [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-make-a-physically-real-stable-car-with-wheelcolliders.50643/), I guess. I translated it in C# for Unity 5, and it works fine.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AntiRollBar : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public WheelCollider WheelL;
    public WheelCollider WheelR;
    private Rigidbody carRigidBody;

    public float AntiRoll = 5000.0f;

    void Start ()
    {
        carRigidBody = GetComponent <Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        WheelHit hit = new WheelHit();
        float travelL = 1.0f;
        float travelR = 1.0f;

        bool groundedL = WheelL.GetGroundHit(out hit);

        if (groundedL)
        {
            travelL = (-WheelL.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).y 
                    - WheelL.radius) / WheelL.suspensionDistance;
        }

        bool groundedR = WheelR.GetGroundHit(out hit);

        if (groundedR)
        {
            travelR = (-WheelR.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).y 
                    - WheelR.radius) / WheelR.suspensionDistance;
        }

        var antiRollForce = (travelL - travelR) * AntiRoll;

        if (groundedL)
            carRigidBody.AddForceAtPosition(WheelL.transform.up * -antiRollForce,
                WheelL.transform.position); 
        if (groundedR)
            carRigidBody.AddForceAtPosition(WheelR.transform.up * antiRollForce,
                WheelR.transform.position); 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SwayBar : MonoBehaviour
{
public WheelCollider WheelL;
public WheelCollider WheelR;
public GameObject carRigidBody; //Car with rigidbody attached
private Rigidbody rb;

public float AntiRoll = 5000.0f;

void Start()
{
    rb = carRigidBody.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    WheelHit hit = new WheelHit();
    float travelL = 1.0f;
    float travelR = 1.0f;

    bool groundedL = WheelL.GetGroundHit(out hit);

    if (groundedL)
    {
        travelL = (-WheelL.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).y
                - WheelL.radius) / WheelL.suspensionDistance;
    }

    bool groundedR = WheelR.GetGroundHit(out hit);

    if (groundedR)
    {
        travelR = (-WheelR.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point).y
                - WheelR.radius) / WheelR.suspensionDistance;
    }

    var antiRollForce = (travelL - travelR) * AntiRoll;

    if (groundedL)
        rb.AddForceAtPosition(WheelL.transform.up * -antiRollForce,
            WheelL.transform.position);
    if (groundedR)
        rb.AddForceAtPosition(WheelR.transform.up * antiRollForce,
            WheelR.transform.position);
    }
}
```

I used mine on the on a empty gameobject of its own called swaybar attached inside the car so a few changes from the above one to suit.
Add it twice and you can include rear right and left in one script and front right and left in the other.

Answer (score -1):

I attempted to code my own script and it apears to make the car a little more physically stable

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Anti_Roll : MonoBehaviour {

```
public WheelCollider wheelL;
public WheelCollider wheelR;
public Rigidbody rb;
public float force;
public float position;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    RaycastHit hit;
    RaycastHit hit2;
    //Left wheel
    Ray cast = new Ray (wheelL.transform.position, -Vector3.up);
    Physics.Raycast (cast, out hit);
    float wheelL_force = hit.distance;
    //Right Wheel
    Ray cast2 = new Ray (wheelR.transform.position, -Vector3.up);
    Physics.Raycast (cast2, out hit2);
    float wheelR_force = hit2.distance;

    float applyL = wheelL_force - wheelR_force;
    float applyR = wheelR_force - wheelL_force;
    Debug.Log ("Difference:" + (wheelL_force - wheelR_force));
    rb.AddForceAtPosition (Vector3.down*applyL*force, (rb.position - wheelL.transform.position)*position);
    rb.AddForceAtPosition (Vector3.down*applyR*force, (rb.position - wheelR.transform.position)*position);


}
```

}

Comment: I think you are missing a chunk of code friend.

Comment: @ Uri Popov I don't understand all I am trying to do is the the compression from one suspension and put a little of that on the other side how do I do it?

Comment: What I wanted to say is that I think you have not pasted the whole script in your answer. For me it ends on the line   'car_rb.AddForceAtPosition (Vector3.down * force, transform.position);' but  I think there is more code after that.Please edit your answer.

Comment: Your code appears cut off.